# Keeping a C Command line app running in Mac Application Bundle

Tags: c, command-line, bundles

I'm in the process of writing a compiled C application which uses the system() function to launch a Java .jar file:

```
int main() {
  system("java -jar MyJar.jar");
  return 0;
}
```

I successfully wrapped this up in a clickable app bundle, however, when I double click it, the application exits immediately before it has a chance to launch the jar. However it works perfectly when I run the compiled C code from the command line.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the application exits immediately is because of the following line:

```
return 0;
```

You would want to use `exec` instead of `system`.  With `exec`, your program gets replaced by the Java process and never gets a chance to reach the `return 0;` line.  However, it's much easier to just replace the entire C progrma with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec java -jar MyJar.jar
```

As written, there is **no** drawback to this approach that I can think of.  The C program already spawns a shell process (that's what `system` does), so why not start out with a shell process in the first place?

Lots of application bundles use shell scripts to do things like this.

Comment: Thanks. I initially tried doing this with a shell script, but it didn't work in my application bundle. I received a message stating "You can't open the application MyApp because it is not supported on this type of Mac.

Comment: Hm, interesting.  It had the right name, the right Info.plist, and the right permissions?

Comment: Everything seems to be in order. I actually used Platypus to bundle the shell script. It worked perfectly on my own Mac, but It wouldn't run on my colleague's Mac (and vice-versa when my colleague tried to generate the bundle)